# Vendor parameter <VendorOption name="labelObstacle">true</VendorOption> not working?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, style, sld

I am trying to avoid drawing overlapping labels with vendor parameters.
I tried below option in different versions of Geoservers (2.2.1 to 2.5.2), its not working.

http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/label-obstacles.html

My style is given below.

### I have added vendor parameter in Pointsymboliser after  element.

Point_rule1

```
       <PointSymbolizer>
           <Graphic>
               <ExternalGraphic>
                   <OnlineResource  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="city.svg" />
                 <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>8</Size>
             </Graphic>
              <VendorOption name="labelObstacle">true</VendorOption>
         </PointSymbolizer>


 <TextSymbolizer>
          <Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
          </Label>
          <Font>
            <CssParameter name="font-family">
             <ogc:Literal>Arial</ogc:Literal>
            </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.2</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="font-style">bold</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="font-size">9</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="font-weight">Normal</CssParameter>
          </Font>
          <LabelPlacement>
            <PointPlacement> 
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX><ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal></AnchorPointX> 
                <AnchorPointY><ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal></AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
             <Displacement>
                <DisplacementX><ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal></DisplacementX>  
                <DisplacementY><ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal></DisplacementY> 
              </Displacement>
              <Rotation><ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal></Rotation>
            </PointPlacement>
          </LabelPlacement>
          <Halo>
            <Radius><ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal></Radius>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Halo>
          <Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#333333</CssParameter></Fill>

         <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">1.2</VendorOption>
         <VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">true</VendorOption>
         <VendorOption name="labelObstacle">true</VendorOption>
        </TextSymbolizer>


      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Anyone implemented this vendor option successfully?

Comment: Put some sample data and corresponding SLD for download so that it is possible to reproduce your trial.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response. i wanted to achieve same result as in given below geoserver url. http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/label-obstacles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the "tiger_roads.sld" from the default data_dir and modified it to add a symbol "burg02.svg" with the labelObstacle vendor option and it does seem to work for me with GeoServer 2.6

Without labelObstacle:

[image: without labelOstacle]

With labelObstacle:

[image: with labelObstacle]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<NamedLayer> <Name> area landmarks </Name>
    <UserStyle>

         <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
            <Rule>  
                   <MinScaleDenominator>32000</MinScaleDenominator>
                   <LineSymbolizer>
                       <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">
                            <ogc:Literal>#666666</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                   </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>

            <Rule>  <!-- thick line drawn first-->
                <MaxScaleDenominator>32000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">
                            <ogc:Literal>#666666</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                            <ogc:Literal>7</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
           <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
           <Rule>   <!-- thin line drawn second -->
                <MaxScaleDenominator>32000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                <LineSymbolizer>
                       <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">
                            <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule> 
           <Rule> <!-- test with labelObstacle here -->
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource
              xlink:type="simple"
              xlink:href="burg02.svg" />
            <Format>image/svg</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <Size>32</Size>
        </Graphic>
       <VendorOption name="labelObstacle">true</VendorOption>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
            <!-- label -->     
            <Rule>
                <MaxScaleDenominator>32000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                <TextSymbolizer>
                    <Label>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </Label>

                    <Font>
                        <CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                    </Font>

                    <LabelPlacement>
                      <LinePlacement>
                      </LinePlacement>
                    </LabelPlacement>
                    <Halo>
                        <Radius>
                            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                        </Radius>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.85</CssParameter>               
                        </Fill>
                    </Halo>

                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>

                    <VendorOption name="group">true</VendorOption>

                </TextSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou verymuch for answer. I am getting the following error (but it seems some environment/library related issue in my system. It was worked fine in other systems).                                                                                                                 line 66: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'VendorOption'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: I get the same error from the validator but if I still save the style it works.

Comment: Thats good. Its not working in my system. I will investigate it later.